# Ajax-форма и ajax-запрос

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

Есть форма на ajaxForm. После получения ответа, если ответ равен какому-то значению, я выводил алертом этот ответ, теперь мне нужно вместо вывода сделать еще один запрос, но он не хочет, т.е succes не приходит обратно.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#orderform").ajaxForm({
        success: contact_success
    });

});

function contact_success(responseText, statusText) {
    if (responseText == 'Ваш заказ отправлен.') {
        alert(responseText);
        document.location = '../zakaz-prinyat/';
    } else {
        alert(responseText);
    }
}
```

Вместо `alert(responseText);` я хочу еще один запрос ajax.... Но ничего не происходит, подскажите.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Наверное, не `document.location = '../zakaz-prinyat/';`, а `document.location.href = '../zakaz-prinyat/';` .. Но не суть :)
Я так понимаю, AJAX-запрос необходим здесь:

```
else {
    alert(responseText);
}
```

А в чем проблема, какая-то ошибка ?

Comment: Да запрос не получается здесь. Я предполагаю это из за того что, я пытаюсь вызвать запрос в ответе другого ajax запроса.

Comment: С этим проблемы быть не должно по идее.. Приведите код вместе с новым AJAX-запросом, тогда возможно что-то прояснится